# Generate images with device frame from screenshots

Tags: android, screenshot

In android studio you can add a device frame to the screenshots. What is the simplest way to do this via cli or code? E.g. on some CLI - ideally with the glare and drop-shadow functionality.
Also very interested in adding a device frame to video files from screenrecords.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [**Fastlane**](https://opensource.google.com/projects/fastlane) set of tools. Fastlane has a [**Screengrab**](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/screengrab/) tool for Android. Fastlane has other automation tools that you can use in CI/CD. See [here](https://fastlane.tools/) for Fastlane tools.

This was promoted by Google's [**Firebase Dev Summit 2017**](https://youtu.be/scfOk5SgrKU?t=2).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - but it is not what I am looking for. It contains a tool frameit to do what I want - but only or Apple devices - I am only interested in Android - have no use for any Apple stuff. Thanks ayway.